# Can Xenomorph Blood possibly get through Superman's skin?

Tags: dc, superman, alien-franchise

The reason I ask this is because of this **Because Science** video. It basically states that Xenomorph blood is *so* acidic, it can essentially corrupt *any* Earth-based chemical...

And yes, I'm *well aware* of the *Superman vs Aliens* comic. Thing is, we *can't* really take this as the proper context, because:

1. Superman here was -under powered_ in order to give the story *any* kind of drama; the only reasons the aliens hurt him *at all* was because his solar energy reserves were drained, making him essentially almost human.
2. This Supes was *Post-Crisis,* meaning he was *explicitly* stated to be **purely solar powered** and thus **did not have** the different chemical make up *or* super molecular density of Pre-crisis Kryptonian skin, which was shown even -without_ solar radiation to be nearly indestructible. The Post-Crisis Kryptonian skin doesn't even *have* these properties; his invulnerability is the result more of a "bio electric force aura" that emanates from his charged cells, as opposed to the cell walls or tissues *themselves.*

Even Post-Crisis, that aura has been shown to be able to stand up to an exploding supernova, the molten core of a planet, attacks from divine beings and cosmic phenomenon like a black hole. I'll give it as even that alien blood couldn't even phase the skin through it.

So for the purpose of this discussion, we'd be speaking more about the super dense skin of Pre-crisis and New 52 versions.

I realize there may be no precedence, but perhaps there was a story where Superman met up with some cosmic acid that could burn him, and thus be used as an analog. Theories with adequate research or any canon examples are also invited.

Comment: The problem is that you have eliminated the only context in which a non-speculative answer is possible.

Comment: @Adamant It's eliminating a _variable,_ though. I do get you; we have no clear indications [that I know of] of just _how_ durable Kryptonian tissues are without solar radiation. But... **that's kind of the point of the question.** It goes **without saying** that Superman can survive Xenomorph blood _with_ his field; the thing can stop two **exploding planets** from harming him, so there is little comparison. Concurrently, even with that _same_ level of resistance, he was shown to be _physically vulnerable_ to Diana's molecular blade. So the point is to see if another _chemical_ may do the job

Answer (score 4):

A nearly fully superpowered Superman fights a nest of Xenomorphs in the sequel to *Superman/Aliens*, catchily titled [*Superman/Aliens 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Aliens#Superman/Aliens_2:_God_War).

**Even with the weakening of his powers, his skin (and uniform) are proving completely impervious to their acid. There's obviously no reason to assume that he would be *more* vulnerable if he was at full power.**

[image: Superman is submerged in the Xenomorph acid and surrounded by them, he rips them apart and breaks free without a scratch]

For the record, Darkseid (whose skin is pretty much an analogue of Superman's) treats the aliens like play toys.

[image: Darkseid catches a facehugger in his hand that had just jumped at him spewing acid]

Comment: this is the _Post-Crisis_ Supes, right? So the acid isn't hitting his _skin,_ it's not getting through his **aura**.  This is why i made the distinction. But this is an interesting add, though. Thank you. Proves my theory of his invulnerable field.

Answer (score 1):

> It can essentially corrupt any Earth-based chemical...

Well, it's a good thing Superman isn't Earth-based!

The honest answer is that it depends. The limits of Superman's invulnerability has waxed and waned; in his very first issue it even says that burst shells can hurt him! But since you ask about New 52, Superman is shown surviving a nuclear explosion...

[image: A mushroom cloud from a large nuclear explosion is shown off in the distance] [image: Superman lays on the floor mostly unharmed, even his clothes are barely touched. He's in the fetal position hugging onto a body wrapped in red material]

...so the good money is that he could shrug off a little acid.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question asked. Superman has been shown to be vulnerable to a wide range of substances even if a nuke isn't gonna kill him.

Comment: Keep in mind that in this example _here,_ Supes and Diana had been beaten down **badly** and weakened by a HYPER Solar powered Zod & Ursa [thanks to a vindictive sun god, Apollo] and were _already_ injured, bruised, bleeding and locked in a solar-radiation shielded Nuclear reactor before Diana used her god forged sword to _literally_ split the plutonium atom in their faces. I get where you point is, though, but while this _does_ go towards showing his high durability, it's not really proof of effectiveness against acid.